# Azure Log Analytics API returns InvalidAuthorization even though the credentials are correct

Tags: azure, http, authorization, azure-log-analytics

The Azure Log Analytics API is returning this message:

`{"Error":"InvalidAuthorization","Message":"An invalid signature was specified in the Authorization header"}`

Even though the Authorization: SharedKey header is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Azure Log Analytics API does not support content type extensions and most modern http clients will generate a request header like this:

`Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

This will not work and you will get the cryptic response message above.

Overriding the header to simply:

`Content-Type: application/json`

Will fix the problem